# How can I compile all .thrift files (*.thrift)

Tags: thrift

How can I compile all .thrift files (*.thrift) in a directory?
It's easy to use maven-plugin to compile, but without maven ,how ?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, use the method described in [THRIFT-3013](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-3013?focusedCommentId=14345559&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14345559).

> sy, you have 2 Thrift IDL files, like with the tutorial. One #include's the other. In that case, you call `thrift -gen whatever -r NameOfTheOuterFile.thrift` to generate the code recursively. The key is the `-r` switch here. [If the files don't inlcude each other] set up a dummy IDL file file that only holds a bunch of #includes.

Other than that, you will have to shellscript it<sup>1)</sup>, unless that feature finally finds its way into the sources.

---

<sup>1)</sup> e.g. for Windows sth like:

```
 for %%a in (*.thrift) do thrift -gen csharp %%a
```

Comment: this might be solution